# Dynamically adding nodes to d3.js Force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having trouble with dynamically adding nodes on to a d3.js force directed graph and I was wondering if anyone here could shed some light on the subject.

The problem I am having is that I want the tick function to transform *all* nodes on the graph and not just the newly added ones.

Below are the functions I use for adding nodes and handling the transformation:

```
// Function to handle tick event
function tick() {
     tick_path.attr("d", function(d) {
     var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
     dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
     dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + 
        d.source.x + "," + 
        d.source.y + "L" + 
        d.target.x + "," + 
        d.target.y;
     });

     tick_node.attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
 }


 /**
   * Append nodes to graph.
   */
 function addNodes2Graph(){

    // define the nodes
       // selection will return none in the first insert
       // enter() removes duplicates (assigning nodes = nodes.enter() returns only the non-duplicates)
    var nodes = viz.selectAll(".node") 
    .data(g_nodes)
    .enter().append("g") 
    .on("click", nodeClick)
    .call(force.drag);

    // From here on, only non-duplicates are left
    nodes
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 12)
        .attr("class", "node");

    nodes.append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("xlink:href", "img/computer.svg")
    .attr("x", "-8px")
    .attr("y", "-8px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
    .attr("height", "16px");

   // add the text 
    nodes.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.ip; });


     return nodes;
 }

 // Execution (snippet)

 // Add new nodes
 tick_node = addNodes2Graph();
 // Add new paths
 tick_path = addPaths2Graph();


 // Restart graph
 force
.nodes(g_nodes) // g_nodes is an array which stores unique nodes
.links(g_edges) // g_edges stores unique edges
.size([width, height])
.gravity(0.05)
.charge(-700)
.friction(0.3)
.linkDistance(150)
.on("tick", tick)
.start();
```

I think the problem is that I only get non-duplicated results returned from addNodes2Graph which I then use in the `tick` function but I'm not sure how I could achieve this without adding duplicated nodes on to the graph.

At the moment, it's either adding duplicated elements on to the graph or transform only the new nodes on `tick`.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're adding nodes only to the DOM, not to the force layout. To recap, here's what you need to do to add nodes to the force layout.

- Add elements to the array that the force layout uses for its nodes. This needs to be the *same array* that you passed in initially, i.e. you can't create a new array and pass that it if you want smooth behaviour. Modifying `force.nodes()` should work fine.
- Do the same for the links.
- Add the new DOM elements using `.data().enter()` with the new data.
- No change to the `tick` function should be required as adding the nodes and DOM elements is done elsewhere.

After adding the new nodes/links, you need to call `force.start()` again to have it take them into account.

Comment: The documentation indicates that you have to call force.start() again for it to recognize the new nodes. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start Is this incorrect?

Comment: Hi Lars - that's not what I see, without adding force.start() D3 seems to ignore new nodes added.

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear -- I mean that you are correct, you indeed need to call `force.start()`. I'll update the answer. Thanks.