# Add node to force directed graph in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, graph, redraw

I've found a nice example of a force directed graph in d3.js version 7 that I wanted to extend: https://observablehq.com/@brunolaranjeira/d3-v6-force-directed-graph-with-directional-straight-arrow

I now want to have a button, that inserts some new nodes and the according links into the graph. Unfortunately this does not work and I don't find any documentation or good examples for this.

I've found this description for adding data, but it's fairly old and not working with d3.js v7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702436/3920200

Any ideas or code examples on how to add nodes and links to an existing graph with nice rerendering?

I've added an example where I tried to add some data to the existing arrays, but I don't whether even the approach is correct.

```js
const graph = {
  "nodes": [
    { "id": "A", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "B", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "C", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "D", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "E", "group": 3 }
  ],
  "links": [
    { "source": "A", "target": "B", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "A", "target": "C", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "B", "target": "D", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "A", "target": "E", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "A", "target": "D", "value": 2 }
  ]
}
const links = graph.links.map(d => Object.create(d));
const nodes = graph.nodes.map(d => Object.create(d));
const types = Array.from(new Set(links.map(d => d.type)));

const simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force(
    'link',
    d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id),
  )
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-300))
  .force('x', d3.forceX())
  .force('y', d3.forceY())
  .force(
    'collide',
    d3.forceCollide(d => 65),
  )
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(500, 500));

const drag = (simulation) => {
  function dragstarted(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(event, d) {
    d.fx = event.x;
    d.fy = event.y;
  }

  function dragended(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  return d3.drag().on('start', dragstarted).on('drag', dragged).on('end', dragended);
};

const svg = d3
  .select('.container')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 1000 1000')
  .classed('svg-content', true)
  .call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', e => svg.attr('transform', e.transform)))
  .append('g');

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg
  .append('defs')
  .selectAll('marker')
  .data(types)
  .join('marker')
  .attr('id', d => `arrow-${d}`)
  .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
  .attr('refX', 38)
  .attr('refY', 0)
  .attr('markerWidth', 6)
  .attr('markerHeight', 6)
  .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('path')
  .attr('fill', '262626')
  .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5');

const link = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(links)
  .join('path')
  .attr('stroke', 'green') //d => color(d.type))
  .attr('marker-end', d => `url(${new URL(`#arrow-${d.type}`, location)})`);

const node = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('fill', 'currentColor')
  .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(nodes)
  .join('g')
  .call(drag(simulation));

node
  .append('circle')
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
  .attr('r', 25)
  .attr('fill', d => '#6baed6');

node
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', 30 + 4)
  .attr('y', '0.31em')
  .text(d => d.id)
  .clone(true)
  .lower()
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3);

node.on('dblclick', (e, d) => console.log(nodes[d.index]));

const clickHandler = a => {
  nodes.push({
    id: 'F',
    group: 1
  });
  nodes.push({
    id: 'G',
    group: 1
  });
  links.push({
    source: 'A',
    target: 'F',
    value: 2
  });
  links.push({
    source: 'F',
    target: 'G',
    value: 2
  });
};

simulation.on('tick', () => {
  link.attr('d', d => `M${d.source.x},${d.source.y}A0,0 0 0,1 ${d.target.x},${d.target.y}`);
  node.attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
});

//   invalidation.then(() => simulation.stop());

d3.select('.container').append('button').attr('class', 'my-button').text('add data').on('click', clickHandler);

const color = (types) => d3.scaleOrdinal(types, d3.schemeCategory10);
```

```css
.my-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you could create a [mre] of your code, preferably in a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I've added an example.